# select from to view image php

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to know what is wrong with my code i cant see the images from DB. i have looked all over the web for answers and they seem to be all old code i tried using PDO but for some reason i cant get that to work can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

```html
include('configur.php');

$tbl_name="shirt_table";

$email=$_SESSION['email'];


 $query="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email'";
 $result=mysqli_query($link, $query);

// If successfully queried 
 if($result){

// Count how many row has this passkey
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);



// if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from table "first_table"
 if($count==1){
  
  

 $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 

  $images3=$rows['images3'];


 }}
<div style=" float: left;" ><a href="http://torcdesign.com/shirtimgs/'.$row["images3"].'"></a><img src="http://torcdesign.com/shirtimgs/<?php echo $images3 ?>" width="490" height="500" alt="no image found"/></div>
```

Comment: i just wanted to convert to PDO but ill jsut stick to mysqli

Comment: make sure you started the session then, and if you closed off PHP in this `}}
<div...`

Comment: no it does not contain PDO connection

Comment: just mysqli connection

Comment: i cant see the image i made sure that the image was uploaded correctly

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Also PDO is a lot better. If you can switch because you're just getting started it's not a bad idea.

Comment: my mistake. because you put your code in a HTML Code Block the formatting confused me. your HTML is inside your PHP and should be generating Syntax Errors the way it is